# Weird behaviour of .htaccess index blocking

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I had some problems with excluding a folder from the index block in the .htaccess file in my site's root folder.

After messing around a bit, I found a solution:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
</IfModule>
```

I wrote this in an new .htaccess file in the folder that I wanted to be excluded. This solved my problem (unblocking that specific folder while keeping the subfolders blocked) which is great and all but as far as I know, this piece of code shouldn't do anything. How could this possibly work?

Additional information:

- the excluded folder contains a Nibbleblog installation 

- root .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on$ 
RewriteRule (.*) https://url.url/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.nyxcode\.xyz [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://url.url/$1 [R=301,L]

ErrorDocument 404 /errors/notfound.html
ErrorDocument 403 /errors/forbid.html

Options -Indexes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding `RewriteEngine on` to a .htaccess file in a subfolder, you've told Apache that the parent folder's .htaccess doesn't control rewriting in the subfolder. This is because Apache checks the folder that matches the URL first, and only then looks in the parent folder.

If you have this:

```
/
   .htaccess
   /subfolder1
       .htaccess
   /subfolder2
       # no .htaccess file here
```

Then files in `/` and `/subfolder2` are subject to the `RewriteRule`s in `/.htaccess`. But `/subfolder1` is subject only to its own .htaccess file, to the extent that it applies. Without `RewriteEngine on`, you haven't told Apache that the `/subfolder1/.htaccess` applies for rewriting purposes. With `RewriteEngine on`, you're saying, "Use this .htaccess for rewriting," even if there are no rules there.